# How to reload part of twig with ajax

Tags: symfony

I need to reload  part of my html.twig:

in controller:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('PublishDemandsBundle:Demands')->find($id);
```

In twig:

```
{% for n in entity %} {{ n.Id }} {% endfor %}.
```

i need how to reload $entity with ajax.Can someone help me and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with jQuery. I think the best way to do this (I think) is to have a method in your controller that do nothing but a findAll() on your `Demands` repo :

```
public function demandsAction()
{
    $entity = $em->getRepository('PublishDemandsBundle:Demands')->findAll();

    return $this->render('PublishDemandsBundle:Demands:liste.html.twig', array(
       'entity' => $entity
        ));
}
```

Make sure this Action can be called by a route, let's say /ajax/demands/
Then, in your twig template, just do :

```
 <div id="demands">
      {{ render(controller("PublishDemandsBundle:MainController:demands")) }}
 </div>
 <a href="#" id="reload">reload</a>
```

With a bit of jQuery :

```
 $('#reload').click(function() {
     $.get("/ajax/demands", function( data ) {
     $('#demands').html( data );
 });
```

I haven't tested this yet, and it might be adapted to your case, but again, I would do it this way.

Comment: i have a method in controller return entity and in twig:{% block body %}
    {% for n in notif %}
                                <li>
             <a  id="reload" href="{{ path('register_demands_showdemands', { 'id': n.IdEvent , 'notif': n.id }) }}">

            <span class="blue">{{ n.content}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
   {% endblock body %}                           How can i use this to  reload the  list of demands without refresh page.Can you explain me more and thank you for your attention

Comment: have you tried what I gave you ? Because this is exactly what you are asking for and I don't see what you don't understant/you exactly want